# What is Databricks Unit (DBU) and how is it calculated exactly?

Tags: databricks, data-analysis, azure-databricks, data-management, aws-databricks

I have come across multiple blogs regarding DBU but never found a concrete explanation.

As far my understanding right now:
Several factors determine how many DBUs a specific workload consumes, including:

- The amount of data it processes
- How much memory it uses
- The vCPU power it takes
- Your Region
  Pricing tier, and thus, the type of Databricks services you use.

But is there a specific formula or theory involved?

Comment: it's clearly documented on the pricing page: "A DBU is a unit of processing capability, billed on a per-second usage. The DBU consumption depends on the size and type of instance running Azure Databricks." https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/databricks/

Comment: @AlexOtt I have been through the documentation. To rephrase my question, how much of data can 1 DBU process? (Sorry if it sounds vague) I am basically unsure of how much DBU to choose for some particular processing task.

Comment: It's too broad a question, heavily dependent on the complexity of your transformations.